# How to present SKNode as SKTransition.fadeWithColor do?

Tags: sprite-kit

I want to add a `SKSpriteNode` as the Scene whose size is equal with `skView.frame.size`. And I don't know the timing function of the `SKTransition.fadeWidthColor`, so who can tell me?

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. What are you trying to do with a SKSpriteNode and transition?

Comment: Implement the same effect of scene presentation with a SKSpriteNode and transition

Comment: Again, not sure what you are asking. A SKTransition object is used to perform an animated transition between a SKScene object already presented by an SKView object and a new incoming scene. Are you looking to animate a SKSpriteNode to duplicate those effects?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you're asking, but I believe you're asking about the timing of SKTransition's animation. `SKTransition` has linear timing.